# loop button to check which was clicked

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net form, I have 20 buttons. They are named from btnLoc1 ~ btnLoc20. I do not want to code each button click event.

1. How to loop through each button to check which was clicked?
2. Do I need to implement timer tick to listen for button click event?

Comment: _I do not want to code each button click event_ - you need to. You can create one button click eventhandler for all buttons

Comment: Private Sub Buttons_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, _
    Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click 'and so on...
    End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For being noticed if button was clicked - eventhandler is best choice.
But you can create only one eventhandler for all buttons

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    MessageBox($"Button '{button.Name}' was clicked")
End Sub
```

Then in constructor

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponennts()

    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
    AddHandler Button3.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
    ' and so on
End Sub
```

If you want to get information about how much each button was clicked, simply create dictionary and add click amount in one eventhandler

```
Private ButtonsClickAmount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If ButtonsClickAmount.ContainKey(button.Name) = True Then
        ButtonsClickAmount(button.Name) += 1
    Else
        ButtonsClickAmount.Add(button.Name, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single event handler for all the `Buttons`.  Select all the buttons in the designer, open the Properties window, click the Events button and then double-click the `Click` event.  That will generate a `Click` event handler, just like when you double-click a `Button` in the designer, except this one will have multiple items in the `Handles` clause.  You can then use the `sender` parameter to acces the `Button` that was clicked, e.g.

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click,
                                                                    Button2.Click,
                                                                    Button3.Click
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    'Use btn here.
End Sub
```

The question then is, what do you want to do with that `Button`?  If you want to do something different for each `Button` then you really should be creating separate event handlers.  Alternatively, you might have a list of data and you want to use the item in that list that corresponds to the `Button` that was clicked.  There are numerous ways to do that.  One is to put the data in the `Tag` property of the `Button` itself and retrieve it from there.  Another is to use concurrent indexes, e.g.

```
Dim buttons = Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToArray()
Dim data = {"First", "Second", "Third"}

MessageBox.Show(data(buttons.IndexOf(btn)))
```

Obviously you need to ensure that the `Button` array and the data array do line up.

Comment: In case when every button have own logic - own handler for every button is a clearer and little bid more easy to maintain, then "index", "mapping" approach

Comment: @Fabio, yes, and I already said in my answer that separate event handlers should be used when you want to do something different for each `Button`. My second code snippet does NOT demonstrate different logic for each `Button` though.  It demonstrates different DATA for each `Button` with the same logic for all.  In that case, using concurrent arrays is a superior approach because it adheres to the DRY principle.